# Laravel updateOrCreate on hasOne relationship with different values

Tags: sql, laravel

2 models

1. Order, with columns: `id, ...`
2. OrderDetail, with columns: `id, order_id, vendor_id, ...`

Order model `hasOne` relationship with `orderDetail` model

I want to update multiple orders with `vendor_id`.

Request params like `[orderId => vendorId, ...]` eg `[2152 => 4, 2144 => 6 , ...]`

```
    $orderDetails = $request->orders; //[orderId => vendorId , ...]
    $orderIds = [];
    foreach ($orderDetails as $orderId => $vendorId) {
        $orderIds[] =  $orderId;
    }
    $orders = \App\Order::whereIn('id', $orderIds)->get();
    $results = [];
    foreach ($orders as $order){
        clock($orderDetails[$order->id]);
        $results[] = \App\OrderDetail::updateOrCreate(['order_id' => $order->id],['order_id' => $order->id ,'vendor_id' => $orderDetails[$order->id]]);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me to properly update (or insert if not exist) vendor_id without using loop in sql?

Comment: You have to use loop

Comment: @A.ANoman that means if i want to update 1000 orders i have to run 1000 query for that . Don't you think thats bad.

what about case statement in sql

Comment: I dont really understand what you want updated? can you show code example of what would work in a loop? How should '2152 => 4' affect the models?

Comment: $orderDetails = $request->orders;    //[orderId => franchiseId , ...]
 foreach ($orderDetails as $orderId => $vendorId) {
            App\OrderDetail::updateOrCreate(['order_id', $orderId], ['vendor_id', 
                                                                       $vendorId]);
  }

something like this but this will also break relationship between order_details and order table if order_id is not present in order table

Comment: @mrhn I have update my currently working code in question can you look and let me know if anything that i can do to avoid looping on orderDetail